# Scrapy 1.0.3 scraped data has <value> tags using xpath and extract()

Tags: python, xml, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have some scrapy code that suppose to scrape for embedded youtube videos in some pages.

#### Example:

```
item['video'] = response.xpath['//div[@class="imobile-body"]/iframe').extract()
```

However when I output to an xml the "video" tags will also contain "value" tags as well as the scraped data.

I don't want the value tags there, is there a way to not include that with the scraped data?

I know that `extract()[0]` works but sometimes there is more than one video being scraped and I don't want to the additional videos.

How can I correct this?

I'm also a novice python programmer.

Comment: Could you provide an example data containing "`value` tag"?

Comment: I solved it myself by doing ''.join(response.xpath['//div[@class="imobile-body"]/iframe').extract())

Comment: @hooliooo, you can decide to either delete your own question, or answer it yourself, so that others facing the same issue know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by doing ''.join(response.xpath['//div[@class="imobile-body"]/iframe').extract())